# Migrating from Entity Framework Code First from Development to Production

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have been working on a side project for the last few weeks, and built the system with EntityFramework Code first. This was very handy during development, as any changes i needed to make to the code were reflected in the DB nice and easily. But now that i want to launch the site, but continue development, i dont want to have to drop and recreate the DB every time i make a tweak to a model...

Is there a way to get EF to generate change scripts for the model change so i can deploy them myself to the production server? And how do i use the database somewhere else (Windows Service in the background of the site) without having to drop and recreate the table, and use the same model as I have already? Kind of like a "Code first, but now i have a production DB, dont break it..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally i use the builtin data tools in VS2010 to do a database schema synchronization for updating production.

Another cheaper tool if you dont have VS Premium is SQLDelta which ive used in the past and is really good.

Both tools connect to the two database versions and allow you to synchronise the table schemas first. Both also have an export to SQL script functionality.

Comming up for EF is Migrations which allows you to solve just this problem within your solution however its still in beta. Migrations lets you describe upgrade and downgrade events for your database in code.

Comment: migrations looks like it could be handy, but till it goes RTM, i will stick with the built in data tools in VS 2010. Got a copy of ultimate, so should have that feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No RTM version of EF has this feature. Once you go to production you must handle it yourselves. The common way is to turn off database initializer in production and use some tool like VS Premium or RedGate Database compare to compare your production and dev database and create change SQL script.

You can also try to use [EF Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-released.aspx) which is exactly the tool you are asking for. The problem is it is still beta (but it should be part of EF 4.3 once completed) so it doesn't have to work in all cases and functionality / API can change in RTM.

Comment: thanks for the tip on EF Migrations and the note about the db tools in VS.

Comment: You might be interested to know that SQL Compare 10 (along with SQL Source Control 3) now has a brand new migrations feature. This provides a mechanism to control the upgrade process by overriding the scripts generated by SQL Compare. http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/deployment